# How to:configure sharepoint 2013 BI features

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2013

I have installed SQL server on server (nvsql01) with the following features:

1. Database engine services
2. Analysis services
   then i installed Sharepoint 2013 under server(nvsp01) and connected to default sql instance found under server (nfsql01)

Now i want to add features under sharepoint server(nvsp01)

1. reporting services sharepoint
2. reporting services add-in sharepoint product
   I installed them using sql 2012 r1 but only check these features  but did not ask where to add them under which sql instance 
   so i use sharepoint management shell and type install-SSRSservices
   give error.
   so i remove them.
   Dear my friend 
   is anyone can help me how to enable Bi features under sharepoint 2013.
   Really need to activate sql server reporting services service application.

best regards

---

Answer (score 0):

the following article is a good place to start

Install Reporting Services SharePoint Mode for SharePoint 2013
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219068.aspx